Limit of a Succession
$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\left(1+\sqrt{16n-3}-4\sqrt{n}\right)^{2\sqrt{n+7}}\right)$
Anyone knows if its ok the result $\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{e^3}}$
This is my resolution
First Image
Second image
Thanks in advance!!

You should better type up what you wrote from the picture

The result is correct. If you push it a little bit $\frac{1-\frac{9}{64 \sqrt{n}}}{e^{3/4}}$

if $\sqrt{16n-3}-\sqrt{16n}=M$ then you have $(1+M)^{2\sqrt{n+7}}=(1+M)^{\frac MM2\sqrt{n+7}}$ so your limit is equal to $e^L$ where $L={\lim_{n\to \infty}2M\sqrt{n+7}}=-\dfrac34$ so you are right.

$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\left(1+\sqrt{16n-3}-4\sqrt{n}\right)^{2\sqrt{n+7}}\right)=e^L$
where $L$ is
$$\lim _{n\to \infty }2\sqrt{n+7}\ln(1+\sqrt{16n-3}-4\sqrt{n})$$
$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{2\ln(1+\sqrt{16n-3}-4\sqrt{n})}{(n+7)^{-1/2}}$$
By L'Hospital rule
$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{-4(n+7)^{3/2}}{1+\sqrt{16n-3}-4\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac8{\sqrt{16n-3}}-\frac2{\sqrt n}\right)$$
$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{-8(n+7)^{3/2}(4\sqrt n-\sqrt{16n-3})}{\sqrt{16n-3}\sqrt{n}}$$
after multiplication by conjuagate
$$\frac{(-8)(\sqrt1)^3(16n-16n+3)}{\sqrt{16}\sqrt1(4\sqrt1+\sqrt{16})}=-\frac34$$

Thanks!! Thanks also for the resolution!!
